# Does matplotlib autoscale have a default minimum tick size? Can this be changed?

Tags: matplotlib

I am using `pyplot.scatter(x_coords, y_coords)` to plot some points. When the points have very small granularity, the tick size is not scaled below 0.0002 like it should be.

I have tried using ax.autoscale(tight=True), but the result did not change. Is there a way to autoscale my axes when points have a small granularity without manually finding and setting the axis limits?

These graphs should explain what my problem is. Both graphs are generated using the same code, but given different data sets. The values along the y-axis of the lower graph are not all 0 - they are spread out on the 10^-9 order of magnitude.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should *include the code* youused to make the plots. Without the code, all we can do is guess how you have plotted the data.

Comment: I didn't think the code was necessary, I just use scatter() on lists of x and y coordinates (I added that line into the quesiton). I believe the tick size limit that I am asking about is not code dependent though, but I could be wrong.

Comment: We can not help you fix code we can not see.  The code + fake data is _far_ more useful than the images.  We can regenerate them locally, but can not guess what you did.  Are you sure there is acctually variance in the y data in the second graph?  What does `np.std(y_coords)` give?